# Virtual inheritance in C++, size of the grand child's object is heavy?

Tags: c++

I am not explaining about the Diamond problem in C++. As We all know that this problem can be solved using virtual inheritance. The query I had is that the size of the grandchild's object created is much heavier than the object created without virtual inheritance. Let's consider the below example for better understanding

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{

};

class child1 : virtual public base
{
};

class child2 : virtual public base
{

};

class gchild : public child1, public child2
{

};

int main()
{

    gchild g;

    cout<<sizeof(g)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

sizeof g in the above program is 16 bytes, Where as the below program without virtual inheritance gives just size as 2 bytes

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{

};

class child1 : public base
{
};

class child2 : public base
{

};

class gchild : public child1, public child2
{

};

int main()
{

    gchild g;

    cout<<sizeof(g)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain me in detail why the size varies with huge difference?

Comment: Your example doesn't have any virtual methods or data members, so the compiler might be optimizing-away the `vtable` entries.

Comment: ok! Could you please explain it more i mean with respect to the memory layout of the object created??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to implement virtual function *and* virtual inheritance is through *virtual tables* (or *vtables*). These are added as invisible member variables of the classes, adding to the size.

The vtables are usually stored separately which means the invisible member will be a pointer to the table, and on a 64-bit system the pointer size is typically 8 bytes (64 bits), and since you have two virtual classes you have two pointers leading to 16 bytes of extra data.

---

As for the two bytes in the second case, it is probably because an object can't really be empty. To be able to get an objects size, and more importantly to be able to place object in memory, they need to take up some space, typically a single byte will be enough. If you create an instance of `base` and gets that instances size it will probably be one.

Why just two bytes instead of just one? You have to check what the compiler does, but the double-inheritance might have something to do with it.

Since the virtual classes already have a size through their invisible vtable pointers, they don't need the extra "empty class" padding.

Comment: Ok in that case shouldn't the size be 18 bytes in that case

Comment: @MerajHussain: What would the two extra bytes be used for?

Comment: @MerajHussain: No, the 2 bytes you get for "no virtual functions" is from the fact that an empty class can't be truly empty, so the compiler inserts a padding byte in the class, making each of your two base-classes one byte, and thus two bytes in total.

Comment: What I actually understood is that even if we use virtual keyword two objects get created. I tried adding integer variable to the base base class and I can see that size of the object with virtual inheritance is 4+4+16 = 24 bytes. Its just that vptr resolves the ambiguity and points to only one base class object out of the two. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Some programmer dude's answer explains the value you get in virtual inheritance vs simple inheritance in your example. I would like to insist on the *heavy* impact of virtual inheritance.

Here the overhead if two pointers, which has a major impact on a otherless empty class. Imagine now a more realistic example containing just 3 doubles, 3 int, 1 string and 4 virtual methods. On a 64 bits system double, int, and virtual methods count for 8 bytes each, and a string (not counting the actual chars) at least 16. That is still a light object but it takes no less than 96 bytes, not counting the actual chars. The overhead for virtual inheritance will still be 16 bytes but it is now only 1/6 of the size, the overhead of just adding one string object.

That means that on real use case, the overhead of virtual inheritance will not have a major impact. The points to considere are more what is adds in terms of modeling, and what are the risks in terms of intelligibility and maintenance.